# Displaying KML attributes (Images) on Google My Map

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-earth

[image]
I don't know if i am the right place to ask this question, i want to display images attached with each attribute in the kmz file on GoogleMyMaps. I can view the images on google earth but when i upload the same kmz file on GoogleMyMap other attributes are displayed but it is not displaying the image.

Comment: you can edit the uploaded data and load the image via mymaps https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3433053?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

You might be using KML tags that can be displayed by Google Earth but cannot be displayed by Google maps.  See:
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps